# How can a subtable inherit and line up with parent table's columns?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table nested inside another table.  The `thead` of the outside table has 10 columns.  The first `td` of every `tr` inside the `tbody` is a normal cell.

The cells 2 through 10 can actually have several sub-rows that are dynamically created.  I need these 9 (1 through 9)  to line up with the parent table's columns 2 through 10.  I'm not sure how to achieve this without changing my overall structure to be a single table with a dynamic `rowspan` on the first column.

This is overtly complicated to visualize, so here's a JSFiddle to help.  That sub-table should span all the way to column '10' of the parent table.

http://jsfiddle.net/23p34/1/

Before I go and switch up my entire architecture so far, I wanted to at least ask if my approach could feasibly work.  Perhaps overall, it'd be easier if I did just switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/23p34/4/

```
var subTables = $("table").find("table");
var headerColumns = $("table:first").find("tr:first").find("th:not(:first)");
var widths = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){
     widths.push($(headerColumns.get(i)).width());
}

$.each(subTables.find("tr"), function(){
    var row = this;
    var rowCells = $(row).find("td");

    for (x = 0; x < 9; x++){
         var td = rowCells.get(x);

        if ($(td).width() > widths[x]){
               widths[x] =  $(td).width();
        }
    }
});

$.each(headerColumns, function(index){
    $(this).width(widths[index] + "px");
});

$.each(subTables.find("tr"), function(){
    var row = this;
    var rowCells = $(row).find("td");

    $.each(rowCells, function(index){
        $(this).width(widths[index] + "px");
    });
});
```

Make sure to add colspans to the outer table's cells.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
                    <th>7</th>
                    <th>8</th>
                    <th>9</th>
                    <th>10</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td colspan="9">
```

Basically you loop through all cells and determine the largest width for that column. Then you go back and set all cells in that column to match the largest width. Its not going to be perfect, so you would need to tweak it a bit. It also isn't the prettiest option. I think you would probably be better served with moving it to one table.

Comment: That works well enough.  I did something similar.  I created classes for the columns and just fixed the width.  It works, but I'll probably move to one table for sanity.